# Centos 6.7 cron bug run-parts starts twice

Tags: linux, cron, centos

Just updated a couple of my CentOS to latest version 6.7 via yum (official repository) and since then i am experiencing problems with cron while executing cron.hourly scripts. It seems that the run-parts program starts twice some scripts in the cron.hourly folder.

From cron log i can see (look at the mailgraph script):

```
Aug  7 22:01:01 spam run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[8066]: starting mailgraph
Aug  7 22:01:01 spam run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[8180]: finished crm114_cleanup.sh
Aug  7 22:01:01 spam run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[8067]: starting mailgraph
Aug  7 22:01:02 spam run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[8194]: finished mailgraph
Aug  7 22:01:02 spam run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[8066]: starting rules.php
Aug  7 22:01:02 spam run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[8203]: finished mailgraph
```

I see the script mailgraph that is started twice, before the first one ends and this causes an error to the script itself.

I have this situation on different machines, since the last upgrade to latest CentoS 6.7. All installations with CentOS 6.6 are working ok.

Any idea?
thanks

Comment: what is the crond version?

Comment: cronie-1.4.4-15.el6.x86_64, the one update from CentOS repository..

Answer (score 1):

Found it!
The upgrade restored this file /etc/cron.d/0hourly that was missing on my installations as i have my crontab file running parts in /etc/cron.hourly.

Basically the system were executing twice the same scripts.
Deleted that file and everything is back to normal.

Thanks anyway!